# problem with typewriter animation on position absolute

Tags: html, css

i am encountring a problem with my typewriter animation effect
i am using position absolute on the texts and this is letting the animation just slide from right to left and not type
if i remove position absolute it works fine, how can i fix this without removing the position style because if i remove it it doesnt stick to its place?

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 home-middle">
  <div class="book-overlay">
   <img class="book" src="assets/images/home-book.png" /> 
   <div class="asd">
     <h5 class="outline-text-1 type-effect">Best Support.</h5>
     <h5 class="outline-text-2 type-effect">Best Features.</h5>
     <h5 class="outline-text-3 type-effect">Safest of them all.</h5>
     <h5 class="outline-text-4 type-effect">Affordable.</h5>
     <h5 class="outline-text-5 type-effect">Undetectable.</h5>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

```
  @keyframes typing {
    from { width: 0 }
    to { width: 100% }
  }
.outline-text-5 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 87%;
    right: 6.5%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation: 
    typing 3.5s steps(60, end);
}
```

Also here is a link of a preview https://chorionic-liberties.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: Did you try setting width, maybe something like `width: 150px;`? You could also try wrapping it inside a `<span>` positioned absolutely and then removing the absolute position for the text. let me know how you make out.

Comment: I have also encountered this issue, and it is not solvable with the methods commented above.